# C program, calling object file

Tags: c, executable

I have written a simple `helloworld.c` program. I can compile it and run it on linux terminal using `gcc` and `./a.out` command. My query is regarding calling .o file without any extension. For example, to run my program instead of typing `"./helloworld.out"`, I want to run it using keyword `"helloworld"` on my terminal. Any hints???

Thank You.

Comment: Rename the `a.out` or `helloworld.out` to `helloworld`.  You can change the file names arbitrarily.  Or use the `-o helloworld` option when you compile your C source file to specify the name of the target output.

Answer (score 2):

Just compile using

`gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c`

The `-o` option is for the output file name

Then use:

`./helloworld`

You need the `./` to tell the shell where the executable resides,  since the current directory is unlikely to be in `$PATH`.

Comment: Then why not `sudo cp helloworld /usr/local/bin`?